# Why is C++ std::list::clear() not calling destructors?

Tags: c++, list, destructor

Look at this code:

```
class test
{
    public:
        test() { cout << "Constructor" << endl; };
        virtual ~test() { cout << "Destructor" << endl; };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    test* t = new test();
    delete(t);
    list<test*> l;
    l.push_back(DNEW test());
    cout << l.size() << endl;
    l.clear();
    cout << l.size() << endl;
}
```

And then, look at this output:

```
    Constructor
    Destructor
    Contructor
    1
    0
```

The question is: Why is the destructor of the list element not called at `l.clear()`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your list is of pointers. Pointers don't have destructors. If you want the destructor to be called you should try `list<test>` instead.

Comment: Nice, that's what I thought but I wanted to confirm it.

Comment: Or use Boost.PointerContainer's [`ptr_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_list.html).

Comment: Yeah, I use SmartPointers for most things but somethimes raw pointers are better.
The thing is I thought that if I have a pointer p, delete(p) was called... but knowing this now it's ok. I'll free raw pointers.

Answer (score 4):

A better alternative to freeing pointers using `delete`, or using something that abstracts that away (such as a smart pointers or pointer containers), is to simply create the objects directly on the stack.

You should prefer `test t;` over `test * t = new test();` You very rarely want to deal with any pointer that owns a resource, smart or otherwise.

If you were to use a `std::list` of 'real' elements, rather than pointers to elements, you would not have this problem.